# Group table rowgroups HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

Lets say we got a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to make a wrapper around the `<tbody>` elements?

I would need to make a table with a fixed header/footer and a scrollable content. I'm already using the `<tbody>` tags to connect specific rows and i could not find a proper way to wrap my whole table content.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: tbody IS your wrapper. You should use thead for a header row and tfoot for your footer

Comment: I'm not sure that's valid html structure, having x2 `tbody` elements as direct descendant elements of `table`. Anyway `table` should be the best option to wrap `tbody` - any other element may be, again, considered invalid. It *might* work, but still wouldn't make it *valid* which could result in unexpected behaviour for legacy browsers. If you need x2 `tbody` elements consider using x2 `table` elements instead - which you can nest withing `td` elements, e.g: `<table><tbody><tr><td><table><tbody>...</tbody></table></td><td><table><tbody>...</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError per MDN *"Unlike the `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, and `<caption>` elements, multiple `<tbody>` elements are permitted (if consecutive), allowing the rows in long tables to be divided into different sections, each separately formatted as needed.*"

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D :) Good to know!

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanks that works!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as answer then - make it official.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need x2 `tbody` elements consider using x2 `table` elements instead - which you can nest within `td` elements, as the code snippet demonstrates below:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>1</th>
                      <th>A</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>2</th>
                      <th>B</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to come up with a proper structure like below. `tbody` IS the wrapper you need.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Footer!</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... so that's more or less the problem... when you use the `tbody` to wrap all the content, how can you still group table rows inside the `tbody`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `<tbody>` elements in a table. It's valid.

```css
tbody:nth-child(3) {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see the same [example in w3 website](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).